# My do while loop is not looping correctly

Tags: c, do-while

I might be giving more than enough but long story short I am working on an ATM  machine program and I am trying to put the "switch" statement in the main function inside a loop so the user can get more transactions.

I am running into a problem where I would deposit 100 but then when I check the balance it is still at 0. I know everything else works fine but that loop is killing me, I would appreciate any help!
Don't mind all of the extra stuff it is just there to give an idea on what i am working on

```
int main ()
{
    char option;
    float balance ; 
    int count = 1;
    option = displayMenu();
    do
    {
        switch (option)
        {
            case 'D':
                getDeposit(balance);
                main();
                count++;
            break;
            case 'W':
                getWithdrawal(balance);
                main();
                count++;
            break;
            case 'B':
                displayBalance(balance);
                main();
                count++;
            break;
            case 'Q':
                printf("Thank you!");
            break;
                main();
        }
    } while ( count <= 5);
    return 0;
}

char displayMenu()
{
    char option;
    printf("\n  Welcome to HFC Federal Credit Union \n");
    printf("\n      Please select from the following menu: \n ");
    printf("\n  D:     Make a deposit \n ");
    printf("\n  W:  Make a withdrawal  \n ");
    printf("\n  B:  Check your account balance \n ");
    printf("\n  Q:  To quit \n ");
    scanf("\n%c" , &option);
    return option;
}

float getDeposit(float balance)
{
    float deposit;
    printf("\n Please enter the amount you want to deposit!  ");
    scanf("%f" , &deposit);
    balance += deposit;
    return balance;
}

float getWithdrawal(float balance)
{
    float withdrawal;
    printf("\n Please enter the amount you want to withdraw!  ");
    scanf("%f" , &withdrawal);
    balance -= withdrawal;
    return balance;
}

void displayBalance(float balance)
{
    printf("\n Your current balance is %f " , balance);
}
```

Comment: Why do you keep calling `main()`?.... doesn't it mean you look at a different  `balance` variable each time (`balance` isn't a global variable, it's local to each `main`)...?

Comment: `balance` is uninitialised in main and so uninitialised throughout the code.

Comment: You should handle lowercase and uppercase letters, because people don't always want to go to the trouble of holding down the SHIFT key.

Comment: @Myst I had to put main because it kept asking the same question over and over again ( ex : please enter a deposit number ) .

Comment: @AliSoujod, that's because you placed the `option = displayMenu();` before the loop... calling `main()` was masking the issue, not solving it...

Comment: Please compile with warnings e.g. `gcc -Wall -Wextra ATM.c` and comment on each warning why you do not fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the main problem is the update of the switch control variable outside the loop.
Reacting to "Q" with ending is somewhat necessary... then only allowing 5 becomes unneeded.
I fixed several other things, too; and provided comments on them.
And I improved testability a little (5->6). I kept the counting, just extended to 6, in order to allow a complete test "D 100 , B, W 50, B ,Q".
Nice design by the way, to return the balance from the functions, instead of using pointers or global variable. But you need to use the return value instead of ignoring it.

```
/* include necessary headers, do not skip this when making your MCVE */
#include <stdio.h>

/* prototypes of your functions,
   necessary to avoid the "immplicitly declared" warnigns
   when compiling "gcc -Wall -Wextra"; which you should
 */
char  displayMenu(void);
float getDeposit(float balance);
float getWithdrawal(float balance);
void  displayBalance(float balance);

/* slightly better header of main, with "void" */
int main (void)
{
    char option;
    float balance=0.0; /* initialise your main variable */
    int count = 1;
    /* your very important update of the switch control variable has been moved ... */
    do
    {
        option = displayMenu(); /* ...here */
        /* If you do not update your switch variable inside the loop,
           then it will forever think about the very first command,
           this explains most of your problem.
         */
        switch (option)
        {
            case 'D':
                balance=getDeposit(balance); /* update balance */
                /* removed the recursive call to main(),
                   it is not needed as a solution to the problem that the program
                   always uses the first command (when updating inside the loop)
                   and otherwise just makes everything much more complicated and
                   risky.
                 */
                count++;
                break;
            case 'W':
                balance=getWithdrawal(balance); /* update balance */
                count++;
                break;
            case 'B':
                displayBalance(balance);
                count++;
                break;
            case 'Q':
                printf("Thank you!");
                /* adding a way to get out of the loop,
                   using a magic value for the count,
                   this is a mehtod frowned upon by most,
                   but it minimises the changes needed to your
                   own coding attempt.
                 */
                count=0;
                break;
        }
    } while ( (count <= 6)&&(count>0) ); /* additionally check for the  magic "Q" value
        check against count<=6, to allow testing D,B,W,B,Q  */
    return 0;
}

/* use explicitly empty parameter list for functions */
char displayMenu(void)
{
    char option;
    printf("\n  Welcome to HFC Federal Credit Union \n");
    printf("\n      Please select from the following menu: \n ");
    printf("\n  D:     Make a deposit \n ");
    printf("\n  W:  Make a withdrawal  \n ");
    printf("\n  B:  Check your account balance \n ");
    printf("\n  Q:  To quit \n ");
    scanf("\n%c" , &option);
    return option;
}

float getDeposit(float balance)
{
     float deposit;
     printf("\n Please enter the amount you want to deposit!  ");
     scanf("%f" , &deposit);
     balance += deposit;
     return balance;
}

float getWithdrawal(float balance)
{
    float withdrawal;
    printf("\n Please enter the amount you want to withdraw!  ");
    scanf("%f" , &withdrawal);
    balance -= withdrawal;
    return balance;
}

void displayBalance(float balance)
{
    printf("\n Your current balance is %f " , balance);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that was helpful! I moved in the display into the function and removed the recursive calling, how ever for the Q to work correctly and quit when i call it, i added this inside its break statement count=0 + 100 !

Comment: I think that was already covered by the combination of Q->0 and the `&&(count>0)`.  Your solution makes the additional assumption, that the count is restricted (currently to 5 or 6) to a value < 100. Both solutions are working with magic values for a variable which has a different semantic in the main use case. But altogether, if you found your solution, it was my pleasure helping you.

Answer (score 4):

You're recursively calling `main()` on every iteration of the loop. Just remove this call, and you should be good to go.

You'll also need to assign the return values of your functions to `balance`, otherwise they won't be able to affect its value.

Comment: He's also missing the return value assignment (he doesn't use pointers).

Comment: I removed them, and I got the same problem i was facing before i put them! lets say i want to deposit, it keeps asking me to deposit instead of asking me to do it then go to the main again, so I put the main func! Now it is working perfectly except for the withdrawing is kind of wrong, keeps withdrawing the wrong numbers!

Comment: `it keeps asking me to deposit instead of asking me to do it` hmm?

Comment: Sorry, I mean to say that it keeps asking me to deposit instead of asking me once and going back to display the main and options again!

Comment: This upvoted answer does not help OP with his desire "trying to put the "switch" statement...inside a loop... so the user can get more transactions", which would require to check the input inside the loop. Not calling main recursively is of course important, but the answer seems to miss at least one of OPs problems.

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of issues with this code... Here are my main pointers (but not all of them, I'm just answering the question):

1. You're calling main over and over again, for simplicity, you could consider this as restarting the application every time (except for stack issues, that I'm ignoring and other nasty side effects).
2. You didn't initialize the `balance` (and friends) variables. They might contain "junk" data.
3. You're ignoring the return values from the functions you use. If you're not using pointer, you should use assignment.
4. Your menu printing function is out of the loop... I doubt if that's what you wanted.

Here's a quick dirty fix (untested):

```
int main() {
  char option;
  float balance = 0;
  int count = 1;
  do {
    option = displayMenu(); // moved into the loop.
    switch (option) {
    case 'D':
      balance = getDeposit(balance);
      count++;
      break;
    case 'W':
      balance = getWithdrawal(balance);
      count++;
      break;
    case 'B':
      balance = displayBalance(balance);
      count++;
      break;
    case 'Q':
      printf("Thank you!");
      break;
    }
  } while (count <= 5);
  return 0;
}

char displayMenu(void) {
  char option;
  printf("\n  Welcome to HFC Federal Credit Union \n");
  printf("\n      Please select from the following menu: \n ");
  printf("\n  D:     Make a deposit \n ");
  printf("\n  W:  Make a withdrawal  \n ");
  printf("\n  B:  Check your account balance \n ");
  printf("\n  Q:  To quit \n ");
  scanf("\n%c", &option);
  return option;
}

float getDeposit(float balance) {
  float deposit;
  printf("\n Please enter the amount you want to deposit!  ");
  scanf("%f", &deposit);
  balance += deposit;
  return balance;
}

float getWithdrawal(float balance) {
  float withdrawal;
  printf("\n Please enter the amount you want to withdraw!  ");
  scanf("%f", &withdrawal);
  balance -= withdrawal;
  return balance;
}

void displayBalance(float balance) {
  printf("\n Your current balance is %f ", balance);
}
```

Good Luck!

Comment: I copy pasted this for testing and comparing with mine, I got a negative value back as a balance and only 3 exactly times before it stopped the program!

Comment: @AliSoujod,  I didn't fix all of the code, just a few main points that answered the question. I'm sorry if I wasn't clear about this. For example, your `break` statement in `case 'Q'` breaks the `switch`, not the loop... Another example is the fact that your `scanf` might behave differently than you expect, since it's ignoring the new lines entered whenever you press "enter".

Answer (score 0):

you haven't changed the variable in main().
you can change the loop to this:

```
do
{
    switch (option)
    {
    case 'D':
        balance = getDeposit(balance);
        count++;
        break;
    case 'W':
        balance = getWithdrawal(balance);
        count++;
        break;
    case 'B':
        displayBalance(balance);
        count++;
        break;
    case 'Q':
        printf("Thank you!");
        break;
    }
} while (count <= 5);
```